# Errors in code that tries to display strings

Tags: linux, string, macros, nasm, 32-bit

I'm writting a **nasm** program which simply prints a string using preprocessor's directives and macros. Here's the code:

```
%define hello "Hello, world!"
%strlen size_h hello

%macro print 2
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, %1
  mov edx, %2
  int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
global _start

_start:
  print hello, size_h
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 80h ;exit
```

I'm using the **ld** linker.

It shows me two warnings:

```
character constant too long
dword data exceeds bounds
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro just replaces strings. So, `print hello, size_h` will become

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, "Hello World!"
mov edx, 13
int 80h
```

You see, you try to load `ECX` with a string, since `Int 80h/EAX=4` expects an address. First you have to store the string and then you can load `ECX` with its address. NASM won't do that for you.

The following macro stores the literal in the `.text` section (you can't change it there):

```
%macro print 2
    jmp short %%SkipData
    %%string: db %1
    %%SkipData:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, %%string
    mov edx, %2
    int 80h
%endmacro
```

This macro switches to the `.data` section and back to `.text`:

```
%macro print 2
    section .data
    %%string: db %1
    section .text
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, %%string
    mov edx, %2
    int 80h
%endmacro
```